# Text is being over written when it's supposed to be appended

Tags: vba, file-io, filesystemobject

This seems really easy (I've done it a million times and never had a problem), but it's killing me.

I want to create some SQL scripts based on content in an Excel spreadsheet. To do this I've created a macro that reads a text file using the code below

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim stream As TextStream
Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 8, False)
```

This is *supposed* to open the text file for appending and plug in my new values.

Unfortunately, it's always *overwriting* instead of appending, and it's driving me nuts.

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks might fine to me...!

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are actually writing and then closing the file?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. `IF` the file exists, it will append to it else it will create a `New` file. Can you confirm if the file exists? `Just a shot in the dark`:- What could be happening is that the file might not exist and you might be under the impression that it is overwriting whereas it is actually recreating it?

Comment: I tested your code and it works. There's nothing wrong with it. The error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just recently built a function to Append Strings to a File. I came across this issue just a few weeks / months ago and found that if used the actual word **ForAppending**,  just as it shows up in Intellisense, insted of the number **8** it worked for me.

```
Const ForAppending = 8

Sub AppendStringToFile(ByVal strFile As String, ByVal strNewText As String, Optional intBlankLine As Integer = 1)

Dim fso as FileSystemObject, ts as TextStream

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForAppending, True)

With ts
    .WriteBlankLines intBlankLine
    .WriteLine (strNewText)
    .Close
End With

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

Comment: @Stian - if I remember correctly, I tried playing with that, but it was screwing with me, which is why I ended up using the text version. It was some time ago and I got it solved, but I think that was my process, as I remember feeling the OP's pain!

Comment: You should consider editing this into a Sub and declaring your variables and constants.

Comment: "I think you just need to change your number reference to ForAppending" from what to what? Question says 8, which is correct! Also you don't declare your variables?! -1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, I would appreciate you removing the downvote. Perhaps it wasn't clear in the comment, but I was saying to the OP  to change the number to the actual text `ForAppending`, which I tried to address again in my comment to Stian. I came across this same issue in the past and found that `ForAppending` worked, where `8` did not. As for declaring variables, I accidentally left that out, because I pulled this from a module with several functions, where I declared them for globally. I do however, appreciate your sentiment and will edit my answer for clarity and understanding.

Comment: Well, at least your edited answer is clear, so I'm removing my downvote. But since `ForAppending`*is* `8`, substituting the one for the other will never change anything. Your error must have been somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. I would have thought the same thing, but I went batshit trying to figure it out. Hard to say the error was somewhere else when changing from '8' to 'ForAppending' solved it. Who knows!

Answer (score 7):

Drop back to basics....
`Open pathname For mode [Access access] [lock] As [#]filenumber [Len=reclength]`

used for your requirements:

```
Dim FNum As Integer

FNum = FreeFile()
Open strFile For Append As FNum

'do your stuff here
Write #FNum, MyData

Close FNum
```

Comment: The basics work nicely for ascii text but will trash the results if you're working with e.g Chinese/Japanese/etc. For that you need to write to a Unicode file. To do that, add True as the fourth parm to OpenTextFile.

Answer (score -3):

It's very odd, in [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), it mentions that the constant corresponding to `ForAppending` is `8`, but it uses `3` in the example at the bottom.

Try:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim stream As TextStream
Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 3, False)
```

Comment: Why speculate? Try it yourself before posting. Had you done so, you would have seen that it doesn't compile with 3 as an argument. There's an error in the example in that old documentation; the [newer FileSystemObject documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be consulted instead.