# Create and manage Log.txt file

Tags: vba, file-io

I have vba code to run which include many functions, and I would like to add a function called "WriteLog" which will create (if it not already exist) a text file named Log.txt and write the string "text" (passed as argument) to this file.

I want this function to be launch from several other functions to monitor their execution. My problem is that my actual code overwrite the text file, instead of adding a new line into it when I call my function.

Here my actual code :

```
Function WriteLog(text)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Log.txt", True)
    oFile.writeline (text)
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Function

Sub Logtesting()
    WriteLog ("Testing")
    WriteLog ("123")
End Sub
```

Output result:

> 123

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB appending to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126551/vb-appending-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use OpenTextFile instead of CreateTextFile.

```
fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 8)
```

[*MSDN - OpenTextFile Documentation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Function WriteLog(text)
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Log.txt", 8)
    oFile.writeline text
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: @duDE you are right, the create parameter will create if the file doesn't exist and just open it if it does. So the create parameter on this function is not needed.  see edits.

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly, just one more question, fso object will be create every time I will call the function right? Is it better to create it one time outside the function to optimize the code or it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Since you're saying you want to reuse this, or potentially include this script in some other yet unknown scripts, keep the functionality encapsulated.  It is slightly more efficient to have one fso declared at the top of the script - but for this the encapsulation of the functionality is more important.  You don't want to have to remember to put the new fso at the top of every calling script to make sure your log function has what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OpenTextFile instead of CreateTextFile like this:

```
' Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Log.txt", True)

Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Log.txt", ForAppending, True)
```